# Is there any way to find the foreign key, when we know the primary key it is associated with

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

When I'm trying to drop a constraint of primary key on a table, I'm getting the error

```
ORA-02273: this unique/primary key is referenced by some foreign keys
```

How to find the foreign key that is associated with the primary key in my table.

When I checked the constraints defined by user using `user_constraints`, its showing only the primary key of table and 3 other system constraints.

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME                C
------------------------------ -
SYS_C0012618                   C
SYS_C0012667                   C
SYS_C0012881                   R
EMP_FK                         P
```

Is there any way to find the foreign key, when we know the primary key it is associated with.

Comment: you have an IDE? to run your queries like TOAD, or SQL Developer?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I'm using SQL Developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check all_cons_coulmns;

With what evr you paste above is the constraint name and constraint type and the meaning goes below.

```
C (check constraint on a table)
P (primary key)
U (unique key)
R (referential integrity)
V (with check option, on a view)
O (with read only, on a view)
```

You can see 'R' (SYS_C0012881) is what you are looking. It is a referential constraint other wise a foreign key.

Try the below  Query. It displays the foreign key constraint name and the column and table name associated too.

```
SELECT a.table_name, a.column_name, a.constraint_name, c.owner, 
       c.r_owner, c_pk.table_name r_table_name, c_pk.constraint_name r_pk
  FROM all_cons_columns a
  JOIN all_constraints c ON a.owner = c.owner
                        AND a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
  JOIN all_constraints c_pk ON c.r_owner = c_pk.owner
                           AND c.r_constraint_name = c_pk.constraint_name
 WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
   AND a.table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

If you have an IDE like TOAD, or SQL Developer, select the table name using mouse and press F4 in TOAD, and Shift+F4 in SQL developer. It will popup a window with table descripton. and if you can navigate to constraints tab and find your details easily!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`select * from user_constraints
   where
 r_constraint_name = 'EMP_FK';`

Answer (score 0):

The `R_CONSTRAINT_NAME` column of `USER_CONSTRAINTS` points to the parent constraint name of `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

```
SELECT constraint_name FROM user_constraints WHERE R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'EMP_FK';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select constraint_name,column_name from user_cons_columns where table_name='EMP';
```